# Is there a RXTX edition for ubuntu32bit?

Tags: ubuntu, rxtx

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download
This is the URL of RXTX download page,but there is several editions and i can not recognize which is i need(Ubuntu 32bit).

Answer (score 0):

Get `rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2.zip`. When you open it, you will find the **RXTXcomm.jar**, 
 which is your jar. If you dig into the `i686-unknown-linux-gnu` folder, you will find the two **.so** files for the 32 bit Intel or AMD Athlon platform.